# Problems removing escape characters in Win8 Metro Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

For some reason I have difficulty removing escape characters in Metro.

An example:

```
Document = Document.Replace(@"\t", " ")
                   .Replace(@"\n", " ")
                   .Replace(@"\r", " ")
                   .Replace(@"\v", " ");
```

That does not do anything.

The sample string: `"public static int main()\v{\v\t\v}\r"`

`Also .Replace(@'\', ' ')` does not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your "@" symbols. You don't want to search for a backslash followed by a t. You want to search for a tab: "\t", not @"\t".

Comment: Thanks a bunch will make answer in 4 min

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`Regex.Replace (inputString, @"[\t\v\r\n]+", "\x20").Trim ()`